# Geo transform matrix

Tags: gdal-translate, hgt

What does it mean "Source image must have a geo transform matrix" during gdal_translate when I want to export geotiff to .hgt file. I know what a matrix is, but don't know how to make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of the driver is at https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/frmts/srtmhgt/srtmhgtdataset.cpp.

From the source code you can see that the error comes from this part

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
451 /*      Work out the LL origin.                                         */
452 /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
453     double adfGeoTransform[6];
454     if (poSrcDS->GetGeoTransform( adfGeoTransform ) != CE_None)
455     {
456         CPLError( CE_Failure, CPLE_AppDefined,
457                   "Source image must have a geo transform matrix.");
458         return NULL;
459     }
```

Continue to http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#a5101119705f5fa2bc1344ab26f66fd1d and check what GetGeoTransform is trying to do. Is your GeoTIFF properly georeferenced? What does gdalinfo report about it?

By looking at the note on the driver manual page http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#SRTMHGT

> The driver does support creating new files, but the input data must be
>   exactly formatted as a SRTM-3 or SRTM-1 cell. That is the size, and
>   bounds must be appropriate for a cell.

and by looking at comments in the source code I feel that not at all GeoTIFFs can be converted into srtmhgt format. Are you aware of the strict demands for the source data?

Comment: I have to add one thing though. I converted DEM to DTED, so I could get SRTM type of saving the file and added DTED in QGIS because ArcMap doesn't allow me to convert to .hgt file. I tried converting to ASCII, to BIL and every other format that Winprom can convert to .elv format, but nothing so far. (.elv format is my final destination). I also checked projections, units and every other thing about it and everything is fine.

if I can't convert it to .hgt format, what can I do to get .elv format?

Comment: I would convert an existing SRTM dataset from your area into GeoTIFF and study carefully the projection, geographic extents and size of the output (in pixels), and then prepare your own data to be exactly similar before converting to SRTM.